# create_DialogOptions is not a function

Tags: web-part, custom, properties

I have a Custom Tool part on my web part that handles properties. It has a link that when clicked shows up a modal dialog but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions is not a function
```

this is the code called by the link:

```
function Initi() {

var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
dialogOptions.url = '/_layouts/MyWebPart/ModalDialog.aspx';
dialogOptions.title = "My Web Part";
dialogOptions.width = 660;
dialogOptions.height = 400;
dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = function (res, retVal) {
    if (res === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { RTEActions(retVal) }, "sp.ui.rte.js")
    }
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions);

return false;
}
```

It used to work, but I have deleted some web parts from the page and now it's giving this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initi, "SP.JS");` before declaring function Initi

This is because SharePoint uses an on Demand Script Loading model. When the page is being loaded, the javascript remains loading. So if you are trying to create the dialog you will get that error.

Comment: this will call Initi right? Just because I want to call the function by clicking a link

Comment: No. It just schedules an asynchronous callback function (Initi) which will be called when the script has signaled finished loading.

Answer (score 2):

found it! just put this on your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    LoadSodByKey("sp.js", function () {});
 });
```

reference: [dotnetmirror](http://www.dotnetmirror.com/Articles/sharepoint/40/sp.ui.createdialogoptions-is-not-a-function-issue-in-visual-webpart)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by using a generic object for option instead of the DialogOptions class.
for more information about using it, visit:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx
and see the example.

Answer (score 0):

## I was try with the first options but not work and found this option

I have seen on https://www.solutions2share.net/en/blog/2013/05/sp-ui-modaldialog-showmodaldialog-do-not-work-under-sharepoint-2013/

```
function ShowServerInformation(featureId) {
       var options = {
         url: '/_admin/Solutions2Share/LicenseManagement/ServerInformation.aspx? 
           featureId=' + featureId + "&IsDlg=1",
           title: 'Server Information',
           allowMaximize: false,
           showClose: true,
           width: 430,
           height: 230
      };

       SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
       return false;
   }
```